# How to export the result of eigenvector_centrality as csv file of networkx in python 2.7?

Tags: python, ubuntu, networkx

I am new to python and try to use networkx to compute the `eigenvector_centrality` of a graph which is a file.csv like this:

```
erwr,dfas,3
rfrf,g2rf,5
fewe,fef2,2
```

First two columns as nodes and the third column as the weight of the edge.

I ran following code to get the result of `eigenvector_centrality` of the graph:

```
python
import networkx as nx
G = nx.read_weighted_edgelist("file.csv", delimiter=",") 
G.edges(data=True)
centrality = nx.eigenvector_centrality(G)
print(['%s %0.2f'%(node,centrality[node]) for node in centrality])
```

And I was wondering how to export the result of `eigenvector_centrality` as result.csv file has following format:

```
erwr,0.42
rfrf,0.38
fewe,0.32
```

first column as nodes and the second column as its centrality? I am using ubuntu and python2.7

Thx ahead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: edges = """erwr,dfas,3
rfrf,g2rf,5
fewe,fef2,2"""

In [3]: G = nx.parse_edgelist(edges.split('\n'),delimiter=',',  data=(('weight',float),))

In [4]: centrality = nx.eigenvector_centrality(G)

In [5]: for node in centrality:
    print("%s,%0.2f"%(node,centrality[node]))
   ...:     
g2rf,0.71
dfas,0.00
fewe,0.00
rfrf,0.71
erwr,0.00
fef2,0.00
```